# Using a wordlist to crack alphanumeric password

Tags: passwords, cracking

Let me first say that I'm doing nothing illegal. I'm doing this for learning purposes only. Using my own virtual network.

So I am trying to SSH into a server and say I know there is a user called urbasnlug so ssh urbanslug@ipadress but I need the root passoword.

I have a wordlist that contained only strings without alphanumeric strings. How would I use this wordlist to crack a password that has an alphanumeric password which is of mixed cases but the number in the password never goes past 100

Say the wordlist had the strings:
pass
word

How could I use these list to crack a password such as PaSSword99.
Maybe in ways other than with the use of word lists.

If you can't help me at least tell me why you can't.

I can write a C or Python module to do this but I know that there has to be something out there that already exists.

Comment: so what do you want to break, the ssh-login or the root-passwort on that machine you want to break in?

Comment: The root password. I'm using hydra for my bruteforcing.

Comment: You would have to get a string, then iterate it to have it upper/lowercased. "password" is 8 characters, so you can have `1<<8` combinations. Generate all numbers from 0 to 1<<8-1; their bit representation will tell you whether the corresponding letter is lower (0) or upper (1). 10110000 makes `password` into `PaSSword`. To append a number, generate 0-9, 00-09, then 10-99. Each 8-character word will then require 28160 attempts, from `password0` to `PASSWORD99`; which is why *brute force* is so time consuming (and then, if the password was e.g. Pass99Word, you wouldn't find it anyway)

Comment: john might have some stuff to play with in the --rules - option.

Comment: @Iserni which is the better way to go about it?

Comment: @thatguyfromoverthere I am going to try using that.

Answer (score 3):

So you have two things to achieve here. The first is generating the set of passwords you wish to try. The second is throwing that list of passwords against your server.

The first problem is a classic use case of [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml), you can have it read in your wordlist, apply some mangling rules (such as appending 0-99 to each word, permuting cases etc), and output a final, complete password list.

The second problem is quite easy to solve once you have the password list. You could just loop over the passwords in bash, but if you're really lazy, [Metasploit](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=metasploit&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.metasploit.com%2F&ei=E8_jUcKEHou3hAeznoCwCA&usg=AFQjCNGRoAA3qPXoKAHeGLdHKLewlrwebg&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZG4) has an SSH scanner that reads a password list for you.

Of course, breaking this down into two stages means you are storing the huge password list as a file. In general you would be more likely to pipe the output from John The Ripper to your SSH scanner, rather than using an intermediate file.

Comment: Hydra also reads a wordlist and is perfect for comparing a passwords against SSH I wonder why you didn't recommend that.

Comment: @urbanslug at some point you will just stop using tools. It would probably be quicker to write a basic SSH scanner from scratch than the time it takes to download and run a tool...

Answer (score 0):

First off it will be difficult to get the root password if you are only logged in as a normal user. However, there are different ways of getting 'root' which I believe go beyond the scope of this forum.

Nonetheless, I don't get the correlation of where you wordlist comes to play if already know the characters present in the root password;which would mean  you have the root password anyway.

Try and use [Hashcat](http://hashcat.net/hashcat/) to try and retrieve password. You however need a wordlist eg rockyou.txt or any of those available in the OpenWall site (makers of John the Ripper, which is another tool which is only as good as  your wordlist.

Comment: I think this is a learning exercise and the OP has artificially restricted the possible passwords to make it more feasible.

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be easier (faster?) to get root via a local exploit, read /etc/shadows and crack that password